# Regex to match a two-or-more characters and replace each with an X

Tags: c#, regex

I want to change any combination of two or more of the characters `[fli]` into `x`'s. A lone `f`, `l` or `i` should remain unchanged, but any combination together should be replaced.

In other words: Match the pattern `[fli]{2,}` and replace it with `x`'s (of the same length as the match)

Sample input 1:

```
office/offices/muffled/stiffly/shuffled/different/difficult/office/officers no change: igloo/visiting/unwieldly
```

Sample input 2:

```
oflice/oflices/muflled/stiflly/shuflled/diflerent/diflicult/ofiice/oflicers no change: igloo/visiting/unwieldly
```

Sample output (identical for both 1 & 2):

```
oxxxce/oxxxces/muxxxed/stxxxxy/shuxxxed/dxxxerent/dxxxxcult/oxxxce/oxxxcers no change: igloo/visiting/unwieldly
```

I'm using C#, but would prefer to just get this working as a plain regex.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll discover [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And in particular, the overload [`Regex.Replace(string,MatchEvaluator)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string source      = @"
  Now flip, flop and fly,
  I don't care if I die,
  Now flip, flop and fly,
  I don't care if I die.
  Don't ever leave me,
  Don't ever say goodbye.
  " ;
Regex  rx          = new Regex( @"[fli]{2,}" ) ;
string replacement = rx.Replace(source, m => new string('x',m.Length)) ;
```

The above butchers [Big Joe Turner's most excellent lyrics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UldZJFsxyc) and produces the expected

```
Now xxxp, xxop and xxy,
I don't care xx I die,
Now xxxp, xxop and xxy,
I don't care xx I die.
Don't ever leave me,
Don't ever say goodbye.
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked out a solution by using look-ahead and behind.

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "([fli](?=[fli])|(?<=[fli])[fli])", "x");
```

It gets the job done. It didn't, however, work in Notepad++ when I was testing it (because its search box makes one replacement at a time). Is there a simpler, more elegant, or better solution?